# Plugin to make REST requests

Tags: intellij-idea

I am creating REST services and now I am using `Insomnia` to test it. It is fine tool, but now my requests and request's bodies are stored in separate program. Not in the project folder and git repository.

I am looking for IDEA plugin or separate utility, which can store my requests (url and body) in the text file under version control, can execute them and display the result.

Is there something like this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a built-in feature in IntelliJ IDEA for that: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.3/rest-client-in-intellij-idea-code-editor.html

Answer (score 0):

I have found a plugin called Cool Request that is good. You can search for it in the idea plugin store. It is free and I am currently using it